# I would like to better understand the output of this code in java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, output

```
public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 2; i <= 8; i = i + 2){
        for (int j = i; j <= 4; j++){
            for(int k = 1; k <= j; k = k + i){
                System.out.println(i + ", " + j + ", " + k);
            }
        }
    }
} }
```

Could you explain the logic of this code?

Output

[image]

Comment: The best way for you to understand what's going on here would be for you to step through the code with your debugger.

Comment: I tried, but it got to the point where I don't understand why it happened. Example why on the second run the K is still 1 if 1 + 2 = 3. I'm probably forgetting some logic detail

Comment: As per the [ask], please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 2):

Code:

```
public class test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      for(int i = 2; i <= 8; i = i + 2){   //Loop 1
         for (int j = i; j <= 4; j++){   //Loop 2
            for(int k = 1; k <= j; k = k + i){   //Loop3
                System.out.println(i + ", " + j + ", " + k);
            }
         }
      }
   } 
}
```

Let's analyze the code as per the value of the loop variables:

Loop 1 Iteration 1 : `i = 2`

> Loop 2 Iteration 1 : `j = 2` (Since j = i)
>
> > Loop 3 Iteration 1 : `k = 1`
> >
> > - The print statement gets executed and prints `2, 2, 1`
> > - The value of k gets incremented to `k = k + i = 1 + 2 = 3`
> > - With `k = 3` the condition `k <= j` i.e, k <= 2 fails, thereby Loop 3 exits
>
> Loop 2 Iteration 2 : `j = 3` (value of j gets incremented by 1)
>
> > Loop 3 Iteration 1 : `k = 1`
> >
> > - The print statement gets executed and prints `2, 3, 1`
> > - The value of k gets incremented to `k = k + i = 1 + 2 = 3`
> > - With `k = 3` the condition `k <= j` i.e, k <= 3 succeeds, thus Loop 3 enters 2nd iteration
> >
> > Loop 3 Iteration 2 : `k = 3`
> >
> > - The print statement gets executed and prints `2, 3, 3`
> > - The value of k gets incremented to `k = k + i = 3 + 2 = 5`
> > - With `k = 5` the condition `k <= j` i.e, k <= 3 fails, thereby Loop 3 exits
>
> Loop 2 Iteration 3 : `j = 4` (value of j gets incremented by 1)
>
> > Loop 3 Iteration 1 : `k = 1`
> >
> > - The print statement gets executed and prints `2, 4, 1`
> > - The value of k gets incremented to `k = k + i = 1 + 2 = 3`
> > - With `k = 3` the condition `k <= j` i.e, k <= 4 succeeds, thus Loop 3 enters 2nd iteration
> >
> > Loop 3 Iteration 2 : `k = 3`
> >
> > - The print statement gets executed and prints `2, 4, 3`
> > - The value of k gets incremented to `k = k + i = 3 + 2 = 5`
> > - With `k = 5` the condition `k <= j` i.e, k <= 4 fails, thereby Loop 3 exits
>
> - The value of j gets incremented to 5
> - With `j = 5` the condition `j <= 4` fails, thereby Loop 2 exits

Loop 1 Iteration 2 : `i = 4` (Value of becomes i = i + 2 = 2 + 2 = 4)

> Loop 2 Iteration 1 : `j = 4` (Since j=i)
>
> > Loop 3 Iteration 1 : `k = 1`
> >
> > - The print statement gets executed and prints `4, 4, 1`
> > - The value of k gets incremented to `k = k + i = 1 + 4 = 5`
> > - With `k = 5` the condition `k <= j` i.e, k <= 4 fails, thereby Loop 3 exits
>
> - The value of j gets incremented to 5
> - With `j = 5` the condition `j <= 4` fails, thereby Loop 2 exits

When the value of i becomes 6 and 8 in the 3rd and 4th iteration of Loop 1, the condition for Loop 2 fails, hence the whole loop execution terminates.

As per the code the print statement is within the Loop 3 and the value of `k` is dependent on `i` and `j` variables.

Point to be remembered is that whenever a loop completes it's execution it's variable gets reset.
In this code since multiple loops are involved, we also need to understand that the increment operation of the outer loop happens only when it's inner loop have completed it's execution. In that case whenever the outer loop increment happens the inner loop starts it's execution fresh.

For instance every time the value of j changes (increment operation of Loop 2 happens), the Loop 3 starts it's execution from it's initial value `k = 1`.(Technically speaking the scope of variable `k` is only within the Loop 3)

I hope this answer helps...

Answer (score 0):

If the `k` loop is done, and j iterates, **k completely resets**. k does not 'remember' its value. Remember, this:

```
for (init; check; iter) { code }
```

Is identical to:

```
init;
while (check) {
  code
  iter
}
```

So, if the `j` loop loops, the `k` loop runs *from the beginning*, notably *including* `int k = 1`, k resets. It does this in any case (once you get to a closing brace, all variables declared in that scope completely disappear).

### `2, 2, 1`

- The i loop is on iteration 0: First time through it's 2, easy enough.
- The j loop is on iteration 0, so equal to `i`, so, also 2.
- The k loop is on iteration 0, so 1.
- k iterates first, so runs `k = k + i`. k is now 3. `k <= 2` is no longer true, thus k iterates only once and breaks off. `k` is gone.
- j now iterates: `j++` is executed. `3 <= 4` is true, so j loops.

### `2, 3, 1`

- The i loop is still on iteration 0 (`2`).
- The j loop is on iteration 1, so equal to `3`.
- The k loop is on iteration 0, so 1.
- k iterates, so runs `k = k + i`. k is now 3. `k <= 3` is still true, so k loops.

### `2, 3, 3`

- The i loop is still on iteration 0 (`2`).
- The j loop is on iteration 1, so equal to `3`.
- The k loop is on iteration 1, so `3`.
- k iterates, so runs `k = k + i`. k is now 5. `k <= 3` is no longer true, so k is done.

### `2, 4, 1`

- The i loop is still on iteration 0 (`2`).
- The j loop is on iteration 2, so equal to `4`.
- The k loop is on iteration 1, so `3`.
- k iterates, so runs `k = k + i`. k is now 5. `k <= 3` is no longer true, so k is done.
- j now iterates: `j++` is executed. `4 <= 4` is true, so j loops.

and so on.